# How to get the profile picture from ProfilePictureView to store in the database

Tags: android, facebook-android-sdk

I have successfully integrated facebook login in my android app.So I am displaying user profile data like name,email and picture.

Now I need to store user data such as name,email and profile picture in database. I know how to get the name and email since it can be get from TextViews. **But I am struggling to get the profile picture.**

**The profile picture is displayed using ProfilePictureView.**

I tried to convert that image on ProfilePictureView to byte array, but it is not working.(Normally this works with ImageView ,Imagebuttons, **but it is not working with ProfilePictureView**)

```
    pic.setProfileId(user.getId());
    ImageView imageView = (ImageView)pic.getChildAt(0);
    Bitmap bmp = ((BitmapDrawable) imageView.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
    image_ = convertImageToByte(bmp); //image_ is a byte[]

    private byte[] convertImageToByte(Bitmap bitmap) {
       ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
       bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, stream);
       return stream.toByteArray();
    }
```

I am getting an image like this instead of the real profile picture.

[image]

Is there anyway to store the image? (like a link to get the profile picture to store so I can retrieve the image using the link at later time)
Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Try this. It worked for me

```
private ProfilePictureView profilepic;
```

In OnCreate Method type:

```
profilepic = (ProfilePictureView) findViewById(R.id.<profilepicture id>);
profilepic.setProfileId(id of user (string));
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks! This is exactly what I needed, I called the setProfileID() method in the success callback for login.

Answer (score 1):

i used this and it's working ok:

```
profileImageView = ((ImageView)faceBookProfilePictureView.getChildAt(0));
                            bitmap  = ((BitmapDrawable)profileImageView.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
                              circular.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```

where "circular" it's CircularImageView Object.